# Cannot run parallel tests with @Factory testng annotation on java

Tags: java, testng, factory

So I use @Factory to run one test with 5 different emails, but I get **wrong number of arguments** exception and I can't see the full error trace on console. I use TestNG. Here's my code:

```
package com.task.lab.facadetask;

public class GmailTest {
    private WebDriver driver;
    private static List<User> usersList;
    static List<TestMessage> mess;

    public GmailTest(){}


    @Factory(dataProviderClass = GmailTest.class, dataProvider = "getData")
    public GmailTest(WebDriver driver,List<User> usersList, List<TestMessage> mess ){
        this.driver = driver;
        GmailTest.usersList = usersList;
        GmailTest.mess = mess;
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUpDriver(){
        driver = DriverObject.getDriver();
    }

    @DataProvider
    public static Object[][] getData() {
        File usersXml = new File("src\\\\main\\\\java\\\\com\\\\task\\\\lab\\\\facadetask\\\\testdata\\\\users.xml");

        try {
            usersList = JAXB.unmarshal(usersXml);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        TestMessages messages =  UnMarshell.unmarshaller();
        assert messages != null;
        mess = messages.getTestMessages();
        return new Object[][]{
                {mess.get(0), usersList.get(0)},
                {mess.get(1), usersList.get(1)},
                {mess.get(2), usersList.get(2)},
        };
    }

    @Test
    public void testGmail(TestMessage message, User users) {
        String gmailURL = "https://accounts.google.com/signin";
        driver.get(gmailURL);
        Login loginPage = new Login();
        loginPage.login(users.getEmail(), users.getPassword());
        GmailMessage gmailPage = new GmailMessage();
        gmailPage.sendMessage(message.getReceiver(), message.getSubject(), message.getMessage());
        gmailPage.removeMessage();
        Assert.assertTrue(gmailPage.isRemoved());
    }
    @AfterMethod
    public void quitBrowser(){
        try{
            driver.close();
        }finally{
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
}
```

My assumption is that it could be caused by changing the original non static lists of users and messages to static, but DataProvider method needs to be static. Could someone guide me on what am I doing wrong?
UPD:So, I removed **@BeforeMethod** and included driver in **@DataProvider** as Krishnan suggested but it gives me the same error, wrong number of arguments. Here's what the DataProvider starts with for now:

```
@DataProvider
public static Object[][] getData() {
    driver = DriverObject.getDriver();
    File usersXml = new File   //The rest remains the same
```

Also, I tried to initialize driver in BeforeMethod but in this case Test doesn't see it. It looks like this:

```
@BeforeMethod
public void setUpDriver(){
    WebDriver driver = DriverObject.getDriver();
}
```

Maybe someone can provide me with a valid analogue of Factory so I can run 5 parallel tests simultaniously? I am open for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Your factory method is defined to accept 3 arguments.

```java
@Factory(dataProviderClass = GmailTest.class, dataProvider = "getData")
public GmailTest(WebDriver driver,List<User> usersList, List<TestMessage> mess ){
    this.driver = driver;
    GmailTest.usersList = usersList;
    GmailTest.mess = mess;
}
```

Your data provider is only providing 2 parameters. WebDriver is not being provided by your data provider.

You can do one of the following :

- Either enhance your data provider to include the WebDriver object via a call to `DriverObject.getDriver()` and remove your `@BeforeMethod` method (or)
- Alter your constructor's signature to not accept a WebDriver instance, but initialize the class's WebDriver instance via the `@BeforeMethod`.

That should fix your problem.

**EDIT: The question has been updated. So updating my answer as well.**

Looking at the updates to the question, the answer is still the same on a high level. Now including a sample as well, which explains the answer.

**Mocking how the User class could look like**

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class User {
    private String name;

    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public static List<User> newUsers(String... names) {
        List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String name : names) {
            users.add(new User(name));
        }
        return users;
    }
}
```

**Mocking how the TestMessage class could look like**

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

public class TestMessage {
    private String text;

    public TestMessage(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public static List<TestMessage> newMessages(int howMany) {
        List<TestMessage> msgs = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++) {
            msgs.add(new TestMessage(UUID.randomUUID().toString()));
        }
        return msgs;
    }
}
```

**Here's how the test class should look like**

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Factory;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class GmailTest {
    private WebDriver driver;
    private List<User> users;
    private List<TestMessage> testMessages;

    @Factory(dataProvider = "getData")
    public GmailTest(WebDriver driver, List<User> users, List<TestMessage> testMessages) {
        this.driver = driver;
        this.users = users;
        this.testMessages = testMessages;
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
        Assert.assertNotNull(driver);
        Assert.assertNotNull(users);
        Assert.assertNotNull(testMessages);
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void cleanupDrivers() {
        if (driver != null) {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "getData")
    public static Object[][] getData() {
        List<User> users = User.newUsers("Jack", "Daniel", "John");
        int size = users.size();
        List<TestMessage> testMessages = TestMessage.newMessages(size);
        Object[][] data = new Object[size][1];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            data[i] = new Object[]{new FirefoxDriver(), Collections.singletonList(users.get(i)),
                    Collections.singletonList(testMessages.get(0))};
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

**Here's the execution logs**

```
1518271888011   geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.19.1
1518271888131   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:14727
1518271888627   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin" "-marionette" "-profile" "/var/folders/mj/81r6v7nn5lqgqgtfl18spfpw0000gn/T/rust_mozprofile.5mkpumai11hO"
1518271889362   Marionette  INFO    Enabled via --marionette
2018-02-10 19:41:30.336 plugin-container[53151:969522] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0xad33, name = 'com.apple.tsm.portname'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.
1518271890773   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 52891
1518271890793   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
Feb 10, 2018 7:41:30 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
1518271890961   geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.19.1
1518271891060   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:6639
2018-02-10 19:41:31.225 plugin-container[53152:969613] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0xaa37, name = 'com.apple.tsm.portname'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.
1518271891259   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin" "-marionette" "-profile" "/var/folders/mj/81r6v7nn5lqgqgtfl18spfpw0000gn/T/rust_mozprofile.npquNnysdwGI"
1518271891832   Marionette  INFO    Enabled via --marionette
2018-02-10 19:41:32.786 plugin-container[53155:969741] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0xab3f, name = 'com.apple.tsm.portname'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.
1518271893243   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 53150
1518271893342   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
Feb 10, 2018 7:41:33 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
1518271893499   geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.19.1
1518271893590   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:48408
2018-02-10 19:41:33.681 plugin-container[53156:969822] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0x7c37, name = 'com.apple.tsm.portname'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.
1518271893810   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin" "-marionette" "-profile" "/var/folders/mj/81r6v7nn5lqgqgtfl18spfpw0000gn/T/rust_mozprofile.65SomKttNwQP"
1518271894377   Marionette  INFO    Enabled via --marionette
2018-02-10 19:41:35.326 plugin-container[53159:969958] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0x1523b, name = 'com.apple.tsm.portname'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.
1518271895785   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 53451
1518271895824   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
Feb 10, 2018 7:41:35 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
[GFX1-]: Receive IPC close with reason=AbnormalShutdown
1518271896172   addons.xpi  WARN    Exception running bootstrap method shutdown on activity-stream@mozilla.org: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIObserverService.removeObserver]"  nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  location: "JS frame :: resource://activity-stream/lib/SnippetsFeed.jsm :: uninit :: line 125"  data: no] Stack trace: uninit()@resource://activity-stream/lib/SnippetsFeed.jsm:125 < onAction()@resource://activity-stream/lib/SnippetsFeed.jsm:141 < _middleware/</<()@resource://activity-stream/lib/Store.jsm:51 < Store/this[method]()@resource://activity-stream/lib/Store.jsm:30 < uninit()@resource://activity-stream/lib/Store.jsm:153 < uninit()@resource://activity-stream/lib/ActivityStream.jsm:278 < uninit()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/activity-stream@mozilla.org.xpi!/bootstrap.js:80 < shutdown()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/activity-stream@mozilla.org.xpi!/bootstrap.js:196 < callBootstrapMethod()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:4406 < observe()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:2270 < GeckoDriver.prototype.quit()@driver.js:3381 < despatch()@server.js:560 < execute()@server.js:534 < onPacket/<()@server.js:509 < onPacket()@server.js:508 < _onJSONObjectReady/<()@transport.js:500

===============================================
Default Suite
Total tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: didn't help, I will try to remove the driver completely from my test and see how it goes.

Comment: @annabretsko - What did you apply and what did you get as an error message ? Can you please help share that ?

Comment: @annabretsko - I have updated my answer and included a full fledged example.

Comment: in my case dividing factory and data provider and including suite.xml did the trick. But thanks, that's a good example.